# Unable to reboot and/or shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, reboot

```
wait-for-state stop/waiting
*Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel 6
Can't open /etc/init.d/.depend.stop: No such file or directory
```

I recieve this message upon a reboot and/or shutdown attempt. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: How do you perform the reboot and/or shutdown? Where does the message appear?

Comment: Simply by clicking switch off and shut down/restart via the desktop.  The message appears when I do so, as I removed the GRUB splash screen. I had hoped the message may result in some clue as to why I am unable to shut down/restart, and have to force it by holding down the power button instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/init.d/.depend.stop
```

In the open file.

Paste the following:

```
TARGETS = unattended-upgrades samba-ad-dc uuidd cgmanager nmbd resolvconf atd cgproxy speech-dispatcher irqbalance alsa-utils thermald kerneloops hddtemp ufw ntp whoopsie smartmontools vboxautostart-service lightdm vboxballoonctrl-service bluetooth vboxweb-service pulseaudio cups-browsed saned smbd urandom vboxdrv avahi-daemon cups sendsigs rsyslog umountnfs.sh hwclock.sh networking umountfs umountroot halt reboot
avahi-daemon: pulseaudio cups-browsed saned
cups: smbd
sendsigs: samba-ad-dc atd uuidd speech-dispatcher unattended-upgrades lightdm irqbalance avahi-daemon pulseaudio bluetooth cups-browsed alsa-utils thermald kerneloops hddtemp nmbd smbd
rsyslog: atd speech-dispatcher irqbalance avahi-daemon pulseaudio bluetooth cups-browsed thermald kerneloops hddtemp sendsigs saned cups ntp whoopsie smartmontools
umountnfs.sh: samba-ad-dc atd uuidd speech-dispatcher unattended-upgrades lightdm irqbalance avahi-daemon pulseaudio bluetooth cups-browsed alsa-utils thermald sendsigs kerneloops hddtemp rsyslog nmbd smbd
hwclock.sh: atd uuidd cups-browsed kerneloops rsyslog
networking: umountnfs.sh samba-ad-dc lightdm cups-browsed kerneloops hddtemp nmbd smbd
umountfs: umountnfs.sh resolvconf samba-ad-dc atd uuidd speech-dispatcher unattended-upgrades lightdm irqbalance avahi-daemon pulseaudio hwclock.sh bluetooth networking cups-browsed alsa-utils thermald kerneloops hddtemp urandom nmbd smbd
umountroot: umountfs
halt: umountroot
reboot: umountroot
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue running:

```
chmod -Rf 644 /etc/init.d/.depend.stop
```

Comment: Thank you. It seemed to remove "Can't open /etc/init.d/.depend.stop: No such file or directory" from the message. However, I now receive " *speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher" Perhaps I did something incorrectly?

Comment: In /etc/init.d/.depend.stop, delete 'speech-dispatcher'

Comment: Thank you, I did exactly that. Unfortunately, I'm still unable to shut down without force. However, upon switch off>shut down via desktop, I now receive "wait-for-state stop/waiting
*Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel 0"

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [this page](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/unable-to-reboot-and-or-shutdown), the problem is because `init.d` has been corrupt, you should try:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/rc
```

Check CONCURRENCY appears like this or add:

```
CONCURRENCY="none"
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

Comment: Isn't `-P` the default option for `shutdown` command? Why one should use it?